# AngularJS - creating factory during run time

Tags: angularjs

I am using odata service and i want to create helper service per each entity type, so after getting the metadata i am creating the factory (this is done before angular was bootsrapped)

```
  var serviceName = allTypes[type].shortName + 'RepositoryService';
                angular.module('app').factory(serviceName, [function() {

                    function sayHello() {
                        console.log('hello');
                    }

                    return {
                        sayHello: sayHello
                    };
                }]);
```

and I am trying to consume it in another controller

```
 sensorService = $injector.get('CSensorRepositoryService');
```

and i am getting an error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CSensorRepositoryServiceProvider <- CSensorRepositoryService

when iterated over all the available factories I saw that this factory exits

```
var mod = angular.module('app');
        for (var id in mod._invokeQueue) {
            if ((mod._invokeQueue[id])[1] === 'factory') {
                console.log( id + " " + ((mod._invokeQueue[id])[2])[0]);
            }
        }
```

and when I tried to take factory which was "hard coded" all was ok
what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by exposing the providers from app.config so...

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.config(function($provide){
    app.register =
        {
            factory: $provide.factory,
            service: $provide.service,
            constant: $provide.constant
        };
});
```

Then at a later time...

```
app.register.factory('myFactory',function(){...});
```

I'd just be sure this doesn't happen someplace where it could occur repeatedly

This is the same concept as presented [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx).

Comment: Genius idea. Thanks

Comment: Why should registering a new factory like that not occur repeatedly?

Comment: It would execute the factory function every time you register it. If thats what you want then 